# Converting Batches of PSDs OR JPEGs to PDFs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, batch-processing

is there a way to mass convert whole batch of .psd or .jpg files to .pdf?

I created an action and use image processor for this with my recorded action. However - I get message box for every single file asking me where I want to save my PDF.

I just don't get it. Please advise or point me in the right tutorial - as I can't find anything useful od Youtoube. Thanks in advance and have a nice day! ; )

Comment: Nevermind, I omitted the default operation, however I still used it in image processor (my fault) so I still had it turned on - therefore I got the message box as where should the files be saved. But when I used my own recorded operation everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Acrobat, you can just drag a bunch of images to it's icon and it will convert them all to individual PDFs... which you can then combine as you'd like.

Or choose `File > Create > Combine Files into Single PDF..` and then choose the files..

...psd, jpg, ai, eps, wmf, bmp, gif, png..... whatever they are will work as long as it's an image format.